# How to implement asynchronous task in a function that must return some value?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I am using asynchronous operation (using parse SDK).
I created a function like this:

```
let result = try query.fromLocalDatastore().findObjects()
return result
```

the problem is that in console I get a message like:

```
Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
```

As I assume this is bad design I am looking for solution for this.
I changed `findObjects` with `findObjectsWithBlock` but problem with this is asynchronous nature so I never get result back from function (actually it always late :)).
My question is:
 
Is there a way to run this code but to avoid warning in console?
Am I right that this is bad way to write this code in a function, where another approach would be to write code from function in a place where I call function, make it asynchronous and loose the benefit of code reuse?

Answer (score 0):

trying;

```
let result = query.fromLocalDatastore().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // results will contain users with a hometown team with a winning record
  }
```

Comment: Asynchronous this is the issue actually. I call function `let data = getSomeData()` but as function use async code it will never return value in a place where I need it. So `data` will be `nil` and data are fetched in function, but late.